# How to use from_json standard function (in select) in streaming query?

Tags: java, json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I process messages from Kafka with the following JSON structure:

```
{"unix_time": 1557678233, "category_id": 1000, "ip": "172.10.34.17", "type": "view"}
```

I want to print out what I'm receiving. Here is a code snippet of what I've done already:

```
JavaSparkContext sc = createJavaSparkContext();
JavaStreamingContext streamingContext =
                new JavaStreamingContext(sc, Durations.seconds(BATCH_DURATION_IN_SECONDS));

SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession
        .builder()
        .config(new SparkConf())
        .getOrCreate();

Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
        .readStream()
        .format("kafka")
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", CommonUtils.KAFKA_HOST_PORT)
        .option("subscribe", KAFKA_TOPIC)
        .load();

StreamingQuery query = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)")
            .select(from_json(new Column("value"), getSchema())).as("data").
                    select("data.category_id").writeStream().foreach(new ForeachWriter<Row>() {
                @Override
                public void process(Row value) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }

                @Override
                public void close(Throwable errorOrNull) {

                }

                @Override
                public boolean open(long partitionId, long version) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            .start();

    query.awaitTermination();
```

Schema method:

```
private static StructType getSchema() {
    return new StructType(new StructField[]{
            new StructField(UNIX_TIME, DataTypes.TimestampType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField(CATEGORY_ID, DataTypes.IntegerType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField(IP, DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
            new StructField(TYPE, DataTypes.StringType, false, Metadata.empty()),
    });
}
```

The problem is that I'm constantly receiving error while writing from Spark:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
>   cannot resolve '`data.category_id`' given input columns:
>   [jsontostruct(value)];; 'Project ['data.category_id]
>   +- SubqueryAlias data    +- Project [jsontostruct(StructField(unix_time,TimestampType,false),
>   StructField(category_id,IntegerType,false),
>   StructField(ip,StringType,false), StructField(type,StringType,false),
>   value#15) AS jsontostruct(value)#18]

How to overcome this issue? Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This part of the exception tells you exactly where to look for answers:

> cannot resolve 'data.category_id' given input columns: [jsontostruct(value)]

In other words, there is no column `data.category_id` among the available columns which is just one `jsontostruct(value)`.

That means that the only `select` in the streaming query does not work. And the reason is fairly simple (I could qualify it as a typo) -- there are too many closing brackets before `as("data")` that is available on [Column](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Column) as well as [Dataset](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset) types.

In summary, replace the following part of the query:

```
.select(from_json(new Column("value"), getSchema())).as("data")
```

to the following:

```
.select(from_json(new Column("value"), getSchema()).as("data"))
```

Note that I shifted one closing bracket to the end.

Comment: thanks for the answer! It worked out, but now I can see only `[null]` in my console instead of the row itself... Any ideas why?

Comment: It is possible that the schema does not match and hence the parsing (deserializing from JSON to a row) fails. Failing is `null`ing. Make sure that the values are in a proper JSON format (per schema).